# Ubuntu share library libnetcdf.so.6

Tags: 14.04, libraries

I am quite new in linux. Sorry for any silly question.
I am trying to run FreeSurfer (5.3.0-HCP). This needs specifically libnetcdf.so.6. I currently have the version 7 installed.
It is possible to have the two versions (6 and 7) installed? and if so, where can I get that specific version and how can I install it?
The current location and version is:
/usr/lib
libnetcdf.a  libnetcdf.so  libnetcdf.so.7  libnetcdf.so.7.1.1
Thanks a lot in advance,
Mario

Comment: There is an [option](http://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/ReadOnlyCVS) to download the sources and recompile it for 14.04, but the process looks painful.

Answer (score 1):

I installed `libnetcdf` with [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/), and linked `libnetcdf.so.7` to `libnetcdf.so.6`. It works well on my Ubuntu 14.04 so far.

After `linuxbrew` has been installed and updated properly, install `libnetcdf` with

```
brew install homebrew/science/netcdf
```

then create the symbolic link with

```
ln -s $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/libnetcdf.so.7 $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/libnetcdf.so.6
```

and add its folder to your path variable with

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

libnetcdf6 is only supported in precise AFAIK. Some people [suggested](https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/issues/detail?id=146) to rebuild the netcdf module (which is not the easiest one to do). However it is still available from precise repo and you can manually download the deb file from [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libnetcdf6/download) and try to install it by:

> `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/libnetcdf6_x.x.x.x_x.deb`

I'm not sure if this is going to work in 14.04, but is worth a try until someone finds a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the release itself, tested with Ubuntu 15.04, so it works well with Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Download the source code from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libnetcdf6)

   ```
   cd
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netcdf/netcdf_4.1.1.orig.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the archive

   ```
   tar xf netcdf_4.1.1.orig.tar.gz
   ```
3. Go into the folder `netcdf-4.1.1/upstream/`

   ```
   cd netcdf-4.1.1/upstream/
   ```
4. Extract the next archive

   ```
   tar xf netcdf-4.1.1.tar.gz
   ```
5. Go into the extracted folder

   ```
   cd netcdf-4.1.1
   ```
6. Run `./configure`

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
7. Start the compilation

   ```
   make
   ```
8. Install the tool `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
9. Install with `checkinistall`

   This will build and install a DEB package.

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```